# Sync folder with remote using Dropbox API V2

Tags: .net, api, synchronization, dropbox, dropbox-api

Is there a straightforward way to sync a local folder with remote folder using Dropbox API V2 for .NET?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what exactly you mean by "straightforward".

The official [.NET SDK for Dropbox API v2](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet) does have methods for [listing](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm), [uploading](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_UploadAsync_1.htm), and [downloading](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_DownloadAsync_1.htm) files, among other operations, so this is certainly technically possible.

That would require you to implement some amount of logic in your app's code though, e.g., to watch for changes on either side, and upload or download accordingly.

Comment: I need an SDK to watch local and remote file changes and sync them!